# Multiple drop down lists with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got DB with multiple tables like Regions/Countries/States/Etc. And I want to make dropdown lists based on other list selected.

I have tried many things, but nothing seems to work.

This is my latest version :

Core.php :

```
 <html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(){
            var val = document.getElementById('Region_ID').value;
            $.post("getSecondDropDown.php",{ Region_ID:val}, function( data ) {
            $("#Country_ID").html(data);

        });
 }
</script>


<form action="/NewService.php" id="ServiceForm" method="post">
  Name:<input type="text" name="Service_Name"></br>
  Region: <select name="Region_ID" onchange="abc()" form="ServiceForm">
 <?php

include('config.php');

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Region_ID, Region_Name FROM Regions"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach($stmt as $v) { 
    echo "<option value='" . $v['Region_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Region_Name'] ."</option>";

}
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
</select></br>


Country: <select name="Country_ID" form="ServiceForm">

</select></br>


  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

getSecondDropDown.php :

```
<?php
    $Region_ID =$_POST['Region_ID'];
    $option="";
              try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Country_ID, Country_Name FROM Countries WHERE Region_ID ='$Region_ID'"); 
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        foreach($stmt as $v) { 
        echo "<option value='" . $v['Country_ID'] ."'>" . $v['Country_Name'] ."</option>";

    }
            echo $option;
      ?>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qohej.png)

Comment: "nothing seems to work". Which bit is failing, exactly? (e.g. what's the expected vs. actual behaviour?) Do you get any error message either from PHP or in your browser console?

Comment: What errors do u get? try var_dump($result) for a start. What is the output?

Comment: @ADyson It just don't show any countries.

Comment: ok, so debug it step by step: 1) do you have any browser console errors (see browser Console) 2) is your ajax $.post call definitely executing (see browser Network tab) and returning a 200 OK status? 3) Is the call passing the Region_ID correctly? 4) is PHP understanding the Region_ID correctly 5) is the query executing correctly (does it work if you execute it directly in mysql?) 6) are there actually any relevant rows in your database? 7) is php correctly rendering the `<option>` tags as valid HTML 8) is the browser appending them to the right element? One of these steps is probably wrong

Comment: ...cont'd. All big programs are actually a series of very small, simple steps. If you break down the program into the steps you can usually find the problem much more easily. You can insert console.log statements into your JS and var_dump statements into your PHP temporarily to trace the execution path.

Comment: @ADyson Yeah, I got something like this. http://imgur.com/a/63AGm

Comment: ok so first problem is your jquery reference is wrong by the looks of it, it's not loading it. So the $.post will never work because it relies on jQuery. You need to put the jquery JS file in the correct location, or change the reference in your code. And the answer below is also correct in respect of the errors in your markup and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem , you didn't write the id attribute in select tag

```
<select name="Region_ID" id="Region_ID" onchange="abc()" form="ServiceForm">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

And try in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc(){
        var e = document.getElementById("Region_ID");
        var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        $.post("getSecondDropDown.php",{ Region_ID:val}, function( data ) {
        $("#Country_ID").html(data);

    });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks, but now it seems to display another problem : http://imgur.com/a/yEQ5y

Comment: its seems version of jquery min version of <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> or show the line 4, it not load that js, so give the proper url js

Comment: just load this http://crelix.atwebpages.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js this gives 404 error that file not found

Comment: if the file exists in that path, it should load.

Comment: Now it all works, I'm just a little bit retarded today.. wasn't added .js in end. Now there are no errors, but still dosn't show any countries, I will try to figure it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Okey, I will try to find it out. I just don't know anything about js. First time using, and I hope last time. :) Don't like it. Thank you.